# Querying AspNet Identity tables in Code First MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

Is it possible to Query the AspNetUsers table based on the keyword using N-Tier design modeled after:

[Implementing a generic data access layer using Entity Framework](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/)

I created the following Interfaces in my DAL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Library.Model;

namespace Library.DataAccessLayer
{
    ...

    public interface IAspNetUserRepository : IGenericDataRepository<ApplicationUser>
    {
    }

    public class AspNetUserRepository : GenericDataRepository<ApplicationUser>, IAspNetUserRepository
    {
    }
}
```

And the Following BLL entry:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Library.DataAccessLayer;
using Library.Model;

namespace Library.BusinessLogicLayer
{
    public interface IBusinessLogicLayer_AspNetUser
    {
        ApplicationUser GetAspNetUserByAspNetUserID(string _UserID);
    }

    public class BusinessLogicLayer_AspNetUser : IBusinessLogicLayer_AspNetUser
    {
        private readonly IAspNetUserRepository _AspNetUserRepository;

        public BusinessLogicLayer_AspNetUser()
        {
            _AspNetUserRepository = new AspNetUserRepository();
        }

        public BusinessLogicLayer_AspNetUser(IAspNetUserRepository AspNetUserRepository)
        {
            _AspNetUserRepository = AspNetUserRepository;
        }

        public ApplicationUser GetAspNetUserByAspNetUserID(string _UserID)
        {
            return _AspNetUserRepository.GetSingle(u => u.Id.Equals(_UserID));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the BLL file, the only Lambda expression does not contain Td so it errors out.

What is the correct model to use. The only information I can find is that ApplicationUser inherits Identity User.

What needs to be done or changed so I can get these fields added to the ApplicationUser model without it affecting the Code First portion for the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It was actually staring me right in the face.

simply use the following code to get the user(s) object:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var user = context.Users.{Methods and Lambda expressions};
```

for example, say you need the existing **KNOWN** active user's UserName, use `User.Identity.Name`. And to get the active User's AspNetUsers database record:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```